# Rename or label StackSnippet editor widget to discourage non-JavaScript use?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

At present, it's common to see new users leveraging StackSnippets for non-JavaScript code -- Python, golang, and the like -- where they provide no benefit over standard code-section functionality, but *do* incorrectly label code as being JavaScript and provide nonufunctional execution buttons.

Putting them in the edit bar with a name that doesn't clearly distinguish from the preexisting "code sample" widget is an obvious potential cause here.

Might a name such as "JavaScript snippet" be more useful?

Comment: No, because snippets encompass HTML and CSS as well.